# error TS2339: Property 'editname' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: angular, typescript

As you can see I'm trying to edit `Formdata`, here I'm getting an error:

> TS2339: Property 'editname' does not exist on type 'never'.

I used `isEditMode` property to reach `elseblock` if user click on edit button `isEditMode` property gets `true` and reach `elseblock`.

**app.component.html**:

```
<div class="card shadow" *ngIf="!isEditMode; else elseblock">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-title">
            Name: {{item['name']}}
        </div>
        <div class="card-subtitle">
            Age: {{item['age']}}
        </div>
        <div class="card-text">
            Address: {{item['address']}}
        </div> <br>
        <a href="#" (click)="editRecord(item)" class="btn btn-small btn-warning">Edit</a> &nbsp;
        <a href="#"  class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>

<ng-template #elseblock>
    <div class="card shadow">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-title">
                Edit Employee
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.editname" class="form-control"> // here error:  Property 'editname' does not exist on type 'never'.
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="item.editage" class="form-control"> // here error:  Property 'editage' does not exist on type 'never'.
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.editaddress" class="form-control"> // here error:  Property 'editaddress' does not exist on type 'never'.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
editRecord(Record: any) {
    Record.isEditMode = true;
    Record.editname = Record.name;
    Record.editage = Record.age;
    Record.editaddress = Record.address;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use bracket notation: `item['editname']`?

Comment: I tried bracket notation but throwing an error TS2322: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Comment: The elegant way to solve this issue would be to define the type (eg. using an Interface) with the expected parameters. It would mitigate the `any` and `never` issues.

Comment: how can i implement interface in this particular request because i only know to use interface on http.post request

Comment: Is that all your code? Where does 'item' come from?